# What it takes to make OpenACC/OpenMP4.0 offloading to nvidia/mic work om GCC?

Tags: gcc, openmp, openacc, intel-mic, offloading

I am trying to understand how exactly I can use OpenACC to offload computation to my nvidia GPU on GCC 5.3. The more I google things the more confused I become. All the guides I find, they involve recompiling the entire gcc along with two libs called `nvptx-tools` and `nvptx-newlib`. Other sources say that OpenACC is part of GOMP library. Other sources say that the development for OpenACC support will continue only on GCC 6.x. Also I have read that support for OpenACC is in the main brunch of GCC. However if I compile a program with `-fopenacc` and `-foffload=nvptx-non` is just wont work. Can someone explain to me what exactly it takes to compiler and run OpenACC code with gcc 5.3+?

- Why some guides seem to require (re)compilation of `nvptx-tools`, `nvptx-newlib`, and GCC, if, as some internet sources say, OpenACC support is part of GCC's main branch?
- What is the role of the GOMP library in all this?
- Is it true that development for OpenACC support will only be happening for GCC 6+ from now on?
- When OpenACC support matures, is it the goal to enable it in a similar way we enable OpenMP (i.e., by just adding a couple of compiler flags)?
- Can someone also provide answers to all the above after replacing "OpenACC" with "OpenMP 4.0 GPU/MIC offload capability"?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you also provide the link of the guides you have read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link below contains a script that will compile gcc for OpenACC support.

https://github.com/olcf/OLCFHack15/blob/master/GCC5OffloadTest/auto-gcc5-offload-openacc-build-install.sh

1. OpenACC is part of GCC's main branch now, but there are some points to note. Even if there are libraries that are part of gcc, when you compile gcc, you have to specify which libraries to compile. Not all of them will be compiled by default. For OpenACC there's an additional problem. Since, NVIDIA drivers are not open source, GCC cannot compile OpenACC directly to binaries. It needs to compile OpenACC to the intermediate NVPTX instructions which the Nvidia runtime will handle. Therefore you also need to install nvptx libs.
2. GOMP library is the intermediate library that handles both OpenMP and OpenACC
3. Yes, I think OpenACC development will only be happening in GCC 6, but it may still be backported to GCC 5. But your best best would be to use GCC 6.
4. While I cannot comment on what GCC developers decide to do, I think in the first point I have already stated what the problems are. Unless NVIDIA make their drivers open source, I think an extra step will always be necessary.
5. I believe right now OpenMP is planned only for CPU's and MIC. I believe  OpenMP support for both will probably become default behavior. I am not sure whether OpenMP targeting NVIDIA GPU's are immediately part of their target, but since GCC is using GOMP for both OpenMP and OpenACC, I believe  eventually they might be able to do it. Also, GCC is also targeting HSA using OpenMP, so basically AMD APU's. I am not sure whether AMD GPU's will work the same way, but it maybe possible. Since, AMD is making their drivers open source, I believe they maybe easier to integrate into default behavior.

Comment: As of version 7.1, GCC is supposed to support OpenMP offloading to Nvidia GPUs. https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/changes.html . But there does not seem to be any documentation about enabling it in builds.

Comment: @AdityaKashi As of September 2017, I believe OpenMP -> NVPTX is still not officially avaliable with GCC, which is disappointing news for those who eagerly want to use it.  The GCC Wiki (https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Offloading) says: "For nvptx offloading, the following issues still need to be resolved:    Add support for OpenMP offloading."

Comment: Yeah I saw that. Too bad. I think it's not a great priority for GNU folks (nvptx is not really open?) and Nvidia is probably not very interested either (I guess they'd rather lock users into their own ecosystem).